# Gradient descent on python for approximation

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement a gradient descent to approximate the data. With the function Y = P0 + P1*X (or y=kx+b), the model works fine. Here is the full code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor

def gradient(x, y):
    P0 = P1 = P2 = 0
    iterations = 100
    learning_rate = 100
    l = len(x)

    for i in range(iterations):
        y_predicted = P0 + P1*x
    
        err = (1/l) * sum([val**2 for val in (y-y_predicted)])
        if (err) <= 1e-6:
            break
        # derivetives 
        P0d = - (2/l) * sum(y - y_predicted)
        P1d = - (2/l) * sum(x * (y - y_predicted))
    
        P0 = P0 - learning_rate * P0d
        P1 = P1 - learning_rate * P1d
    
        # print("P1 {}, P2 {}, err {}, iteration {}".format(P1, P2, err, i))
    return P0, P1
    
X = np.asarray([1, 2, 4, 5, 6])
Y = np.asarray([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])

P0, P1 = gradient(X, Y)
pred = P0 + P1*X
plt.figure(1, figsize=(6,4), dpi=120)
plt.scatter(x=X, y=Y, c='red', marker='o', label='Data')
plt.plot(X, pred, '--m', label='Model')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

But with the function Y = P0 + P1*X + P2*(X**2), there are some strange results:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor

def gradient(x, y):
    P0 = P1 = P2 = 0
    iterations = 100
    learning_rate = 0.01
    l = len(x)

    for i in range(iterations):
        y_predicted = P0 + P1*x + P2*(x**2)
        err = (1/l) * sum([val**2 for val in (y-y_predicted)])
        if (err) <= 1e-6:
            break

        # derivetives 
        P0d = - (2/l) * sum(y - y_predicted)
        P1d = - (2/l) * sum(x * (y - y_predicted))
        P2d = - (2/l) * sum(x**2 * (y - y_predicted))
        
        P0 = P0 - learning_rate * P0d
        P1 = P1 - learning_rate * P1d
        P2 = P2 - learning_rate * P2d
    
        # print("P1 {}, P2 {}, P3 {}, err {}, iteration {}".format(P1, P2, P3, err, i))
    return P0, P1, P2
    
X = np.asarray([1, 2, 4, 5, 6])
Y = np.asarray([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])

P0, P1, P2 = gradient(X, Y)
pred = P0 + P1*X + P2*X**2
plt.figure(1, figsize=(6,4), dpi=120)
plt.scatter(x=X, y=Y, c='red', marker='o', label='Data')
plt.plot(X, pred, '--m', label='Model')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

This is how the math looks like for the first model:

[image]

These derivatives are driving me crazy. I just added another partial derivative Pd3 for the third parameter - why did it go wrong?

Comment: This is not what gradient descent is for.  It's good at finding the minima of a function of one variable, but not for curve fitting, where you have three variables.  Right?  Where did you see this?  Plus, your data looks nothing like a quadratic curve.

Comment: @Tim Roberts Thank you for your reply! I found that the model works with a lower learning rate (0.001). This is one of the assignments of the term paper (theoretical research is also forthcoming, but at this point I just wanted to find mistakes in the program)